# React Native StackNavigation Unable to Center Header

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

I've been trying to center the text in the StackNavigation Header, but nothing I have used has successfully moved the header. I'm unsure if I'm just using the wrong CSS to address it.

```
class CryptoInfo extends React.Component {
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation, navigationOptions }) => {
  const { params } = navigation.state;

  return {
    title: params ? params.otherParam : 'Cryptopedia',
    /* These values are used instead of the shared configuration! */
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: navigationOptions.headerStyle.backgroundColor,
      textAlign: 'center',
  alignSelf: 'center',
    },
    headerTintColor: navigationOptions.headerTintColor,
  };
};

render() {
  /* 2. Read the params from the navigation state */
  const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
  const itemId = params ? params.itemId : null;
  const otherParam = params ? params.otherParam : null;

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'flex-start', justifyContent: 'flex-start', backgroundColor: '#68BFAC' }}>
      <ETHCard/>

    </View>

  );
}
```

}

I originally didn't use textAlign or alignSelf, but haven't had any luck with anything. I've read that headerStyleTitle is another method, but had no luck with that either. Thanks for the help!

P.S - I attempted headerText as well below:

```
return {
    title: params ? params.otherParam : 'Cryptopedia',
    /* These values are used instead of the shared configuration! */
    headerTitleStyle: {
      backgroundColor: navigationOptions.headerStyle.backgroundColor,
    },
    headerTintColor: navigationOptions.headerTintColor,
    headerText: {
      textAlign: 'center',
      alignSelf: 'center',
    },
  };
};
```

Still no effect :(

Answer (score 0):

You can create new header component and design as you want just like a separate component or a screen. set its height around 100 or whatever you like

```js
const HeaderComponent = () => {
  return (
    // Your heade 
  );
}

static navigationOptions = ({ navigation, navigationOptions }) => {
  const { params } = navigation.state;

  return {
    header: <HeaderComponent />
  }
};
```